# MariaDB and Windowing Functions (or support for SQL:2003 standard)

Tags: sql, standards, mariadb

I have done some research, but have been unable to find any information.  Does anyone know if MariaDB is working to add windowing functions or support for SQL:2003 (or higher) standard?  I have searched the web, Stackoverflow, and MariaDB and can't find any discussions around this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is listed as an issue here (MDEV-6115):
https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/MDEV-6115

Nothing encouraging regarding any progress or ETA.

PostgreSQL has supported windowing for quite a while:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html

Answer (score 0):

It is now. See [Window Functions - MariaDB Knowledge Base](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/window-functions/).

According to the documentation it was introduced in version 10.2.0

This and other features is leaving MySQL in the dust …